# Error when trying to use detectText function in Amazon Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I tried to use Amazon Rekognition in one of my projects which involves in detecting the text content in a given image(ocr).I tried using AWS SDK and I used the method detectText function under Rekongtion service. But every time I tried to run my script I am getting a

ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

error as the result. I tried the Amazon Rekogntion provided demo page as well, and I got an 
[unknown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clgbG.png) 
as shown in the image attached. But when I looked at my browser console I noticed that it was the same ProvisionedThroughputExceededException that I've got previously. The only help that I found regarding the problem is this thread (which isn't directly related but the person is getting the same exception),

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=824338&#824338

and as mentioned in the answers I tried to increase my request limit but I couldn't found the DetectText method under any of the APIs provided. Any help would appreciate in this matter. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try Account and Billing Support > Account > Other Account Issues.  Explain in the narrative that your account seems not to have access to Rekognition in the region you are testing, and select "Phone" as the method of contact.  Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the help, I'll follow the steps you've mentioned